# NSConnectionDelegate methods doesn't be execute

Tags: macos, cocoa

I'm trying to develop a simple OS X application that should do the following:

1. Read a file to get username and password
2. Obtain Mac serial number from server
3. Connect to a remote service to login with username, password and Mac serial number
4. If the user is authorized to be connected with this service it should run an infinite
5. Infinite loop should call a service that connect to another service to get news
6. If there are news it should send a local notification

This application should work without GUI, so I'm using an Xcode command line tool. The application is organized so:

- main.m read file with username and password and obtain the Mac serial number
- Connection.m should connect to the login service and run the checkNews service
- CheckNews.m should connect to the news service and if there are a news should run a class to send local notification
- NotificationCenterDelegate.m should simply send the local notification with news inside

My problem is that if I run the app it doesn't connect to the login service, because it doesn't calls the NSConnectionDelegate methods. I searched on the web and I found that the connection should be in the main thread, I tested it by using the following code: `NSLog(@"Is%@ main thread", ([NSThread isMainThread] ? @"YES" : @" NOT"));` and it returned me that the connection is in the main thread, so I don't know why it doesn't run the NSConnectionDelegate methods. If you need I can post the code of my Connection.m class to understand why it doesn't working well. I hope you can help me to fix that issue.

**Connection.m**

```
#import "Connection.h"
#import "CheckNews.h"

@interface Connection() {
    NSMutableData *responseData;
}

@property(nonatomic,strong)NSString *fakeBundleIdentifier;
@property BOOL installNSBundleHook;

@end

@implementation Connection

- (id)initWithFakeBundle:(NSString *)fakeBundleIdentifier andInstallNSbundleHook:(BOOL)installNSBundleHook {
    if (self) {
        self.fakeBundleIdentifier = fakeBundleIdentifier;
        self.installNSBundleHook = installNSBundleHook;
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)sendRequestToURL:(NSString *)urlString withMethod:(NSString *)method withUsername:(NSString *)username withPassword:(NSString *)password andSerialNumber:(NSString *)serialNumber {
    NSURL *finalURL;

    if ([method isEqualToString:@"POST"]) {
        finalURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Metodo no previsto");
    }

    NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"username=%@&password=%@&serialNumber=%@", username, password, serialNumber];
    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)postData.length];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]init];
    [request setURL:finalURL];
    [request setHTTPMethod:method];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    NSURLConnection *connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    if (connection) {
        [connection start];
    }
    return connection;
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [responseData appendData:data];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"%@", error);
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    NSDictionary *json;
    NSError *error;

    json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&error];

    if ([self loginWithSuccessFromJson:json]) {
        [self checkNews];
    }

}

- (BOOL)loginWithSuccessFromJson:(NSDictionary *)json {
    int success = [[json objectForKey:@"success"]intValue];

    if (success == 1) {
        return YES;
    } else {
        return NO;
    }
}

- (void) checkNews {
    CheckNews *checkNews = [[CheckNews alloc]initWithFakeBundle:self.fakeBundleIdentifier andInstallNSbundleHook:self.installNSBundleHook];
    for(;;) {
        [checkNews sendRequestToURL:@"" withMethod:@"GET"];
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the delegate set?

Comment: Yes, look at the question I added my code so you can see what I did. Where I initialize the connection I found wrote so: `NSURLConnection *connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];` so I set the delegate